# Struggling with CDF of a discrete rand. variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Having been given the following mass function for my rand. variable X,

$$p(i)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{i-1}}{(i-1)!}$$

I see myself now given the new rand. variable $Y=|X-3|$ for which I need to calculate $P(Y<1)$, my development goes as follows,

$$P(Y<1)=P(|X-3|<1)=P(2<X<4)$$

From this I assumed that I had to decompose the problem into two different calculations
$P(X>2)$ and $P(X<4)$, my idea was use the distribution function

$$F(a)=P(X\leq a)=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=1}^{a}\frac{\lambda^{i-1}}{(i-1)!}$$

to compute both probabilities, however can I assume that $P(X<a) = 1 - P(X>a)$ to change $P(X>2)$ into $P(X<2)=1-P(X>2)$? And also from there can I claim the two following things?
$$P(x<a) = e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=1}^{a-1}\frac{\lambda^{i-1}}{(i-1)!}$$
$$P(2<X<4)=|P(X>2)-P(X<4)|$$

Comment: $$P(2<X<4)=P(X=3)$$

Comment: If you have an explicit CDF, then it is easiest to compute $P(X \in (a,b])$ as $F(b)-F(a)$ (using limits from the left as necessary). But if you have an explicit PMF and don't have an explicit CDF, then it is easier to just sum up values of the PMF. As Snoop said, here that just amounts to $X=3$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers!